# Why I can't post in protected questions, despite that I have enough reputation to do so?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers

For example, in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33470/what-technical-reasons-are-there-to-have-low-maximum-password-lengths) I still see the following message:
[image: Protected question]
Currently I have 101 reputation. Is 101 < 10? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Users with 10 or more reputation can answer a protected question. However, **the +100 account association bonus is ignored for this check**, so you must have earned 10 or more reputation **on that specific site** to answer a protected question.

See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/167831

Comment: So I think that message should be modified, because currently is a little misleading.

Comment: @TildalWave So if it describes it "pretty well", pages http://security.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user and http://security.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation are misleading.

Comment: @TildalWave "To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation (without [link to help page]association bonus[/link]) on this site." for example.

Comment: Suggested forwarded on at http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174793/167831